# Find $m,n$ so that $u(x,t)=t^mf(xt^n)$ is a solution to $u_t+uu_x=\nu u_{xx}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Consider the viscous Burgers’ equation
>   $$u_t + uu_x = \nu u_{xx},\nu > 0.$$
>   Identify the exponents $n,m$ such that self-similar solutions of the form $u(x,t) = t^mf(xt^n)$ can
>   be obtained. Write down the resulting ODE for the function $f$.

Letting $z=xt^n$ and using the chain rule I get the ODE
$$mt^{m-1}f(xt^n)+nxt^{n+m-1}f'(xt^n)+t^{m+n}f(xt^n)f'(xt^n)-\nu t^{m+2n}f''(xt^n)=0,$$ and using $z=xt^n$ I get $$mt^{m-1}f+nzt^{m-1}f'+t^{2m+n}ff'-\nu t^{m+2n}f''=0.$$
Since I want an ODE in just $z$, I want the powers of $t$ to vanish. So I must have $m=1$, $n=-2$ which gives a power of $t^{-3}$ in the last term which is inconsistent. Can anyone see where I went wrong?

**EDIT**: Forgot a term of $f$ in the next last term, thanks to @mattos for pointing it out.

Comment: You should have an $f f'$ term. I get $$t^{m-1} (m f + n z f' + t^{m + n + 1} ff') = t^{m - 1} (\nu t^{2n + 1} f'')$$ and hence it should be $m, n = -1/2$.

Comment: Ah, didn't think of taking a power of $t$ outside, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $u(x,t) = t^m f(xt^n)$ and $ z = x t^n$.

Following mattos's comment we get
$$
\begin{split}
u_t &= mt^{m-1}f+nxt^{n+m-1}f' \\
u_x &= t^{m+n}f'\\
u_{xx}&= t^{m+2n}f''
\end{split}
$$
So the equation becomes
$$\left( mt^{m-1}f+nxt^{n+m-1} f' \right)+ \left(t^{m+n}f' \right) \  t^m f = \nu t^{m+2n}f''$$

And, if we divide by $t^{m-1}$ we get
$$
mf + nxt^nf'+t^{m+n+1}f \cdot f ' = \nu \, t^{2n+1} f''
$$
Remembering that $z= xt^m$ we obtain
$$
mf + nzf'+t^{m+n+1}f \cdot f ' = \nu \, t^{2n+1} f''
$$
Now we want to anihilate the exponent hence we should impose $m+n = -1$ and $2n+1=0$.

Hence  $n = m =  - \frac{1}{2}$ and we obtain
$$
-\frac{1}{2}f - \frac{1}{2}zf'+f \cdot f ' = \nu \, f''
$$
and, finally,

$$
\boxed{2 \nu f''(z) -2f  f' +zf' +f = 0}
$$

Comment: The term $uu_x$ should have a power of $t^{m+2n}$ I believe, it gave me the ODE $2\nu f''+2f'f+zf'+f=0$.

Comment: @user30523 Thanks, I wrote $t^n f(x t^m)$ instead of $t^m f(x t^n)$ :P. I believe there is a miuns in front of the factor $f f'$, right?